# How can a static class derive from an object?

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to inherit a non-static class by a static class.

```
public class foo
{ }

public static class bar : foo
{ }
```

And I get:

> Static class cannot derive from type.
>   Static classes must derive from
>   object.

**How can I derive it from object?**

The code is in C#.

Comment: Is there a use case for this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There's no value in deriving static classes. The reasons to use inheritance are:

- Polymorphism
- Code reuse

You can't get polymorphism with static classes, obviously, because there is no instance to dynamically dispatch on (in other words, it's not like you can pass a Bar to a function expecting a Foo, since you don't *have* a Bar).

Code reuse is easily solved using composition: give Bar a static instance of Foo.

Comment: +1 For providing a simple and appropriate solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: Sorry for "thread digging" but I'm wanting to do the same thing and while I think your answer is a good one, I'm wondering how you would approach the use case where `foo` has some protected methods that `bar` would like to use.

Comment: You're saying you want a *static* `Bar` class that inherits from a *non-static* `Foo` so that it can get to its protected members? There's a lot of fishiness in that design (it's rare for a single class to make sense in both a static and non-static context). But, assuming you have a valid reason for this, one solution is to have `Bar` have a private inner non-static class that inherits from `Foo` (call it `FooWrapper`). It has public methods that forward to the protected ones it inherits. `Bar` can then have an instance of `FooHelper` and get to the protected members in `Foo` through that.

Comment: you could use the singleton pattern to have inheritance and static(ish) behaviour

Comment: Another use for deriving is to provide default arguments for Generic parameters. As illustrated in this question, C# does not support defaults but you can get around that by overriding. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747874/default-for-generic-type

    public static class ActionInvoker : ActionInvoker<WaitForSeconds> { }

    public static class ActionInvoker<TWaitForSeconds>
    {
    }

Comment: Let's discuss "There's no value in deriving static classes": I'm not objecting that allowing deriving static classes could create some consistency issues in the language, still people are asking for it. Let's consider one of the best use of static classes, which are extension methods: it's not possible to compose classes with extension methods which would help to deal with ambiguities, requiring less namespace qualification and, in the end, better reuse the code. If it doesn't break the language in other ways, that would be an interesting use for static class inheritance.

Answer (score 25):

From the C# 3.0 specification, section 10.1.1.3:

> A static class may not include a
>   *class-base* specification (§10.1.4) and
>   cannot explicitly specify a base class
>   or a list of implemented interfaces. A
>   static class implicitly inherits from
>   type `object`.

In other words, you can't do this.

Answer (score 20):

The error message is bogus.  It's not saying "an" object.  It's talking about the built-in type called "object" which is the base of everything in .NET.

It should say "static classes can not specify a base type".

Comment: No, it should say "Static classes cannot specify a base type. Static classes always implicitly derive from System.Object." Note that you can't derive one static class from another static class either.

Answer (score 9):

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(VS.80).aspx

> The main features of a static class
>   are:
>
> They only contain static members.
>
> They cannot be instantiated.
>
> They are sealed.
>
> They cannot contain Instance
>   Constructors (C# Programming Guide).

So, inheriting from a non-static class violates the first feature of static classes on this list by introducing non-static members to your static class.

Comment: This is the answer that addresses the root issue.

Comment: It's a shame they don't allow you to inherit from a static class really, as I've just come across a scenario where it would have been handy.  If it were to be implemented, you'd simply provide a static parameterless constructor to call the constructor of the base class, and all of the instance members would become static members...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think C# supports inheritance for static classes.

One option would be to use the singleton pattern instead

```
public class foo
{ }

public class bar : foo
{
    private bar instance;
    public bar GetInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null) instance = new bar();
        return instance;
    }

    private bar(){} //make default constructor private to prevent instantiation 
}
```

Comment: Singleton isn't something I'd recommend. Be very careful about using it.

See: http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=singleton+bad&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f

Comment: I think your example is flawed, if two threads succeed passing the if(instance == null) it will instantiate a new bar two times.

Comment: The above code generates error : Static classes cannot have instance constructors

Comment: Edited to remove static declaration on bar class.

I didn't say it was thread safe, presumably you could put a lock on checking / creation of the instance.

Personally I think singletons are going the way of goto, people assume they're always evil, which isn't always the case. DI can be overkill too

Comment: Considering that it no longer even has any static classes, your answer is a bit far off from what the OP is trying to do.  Also note that any threading issues that exist within munificent's solution would also exist if the OP was able to have a static class derive from a class.

Answer (score 2):

For everyone finding this question many years later, you might be able to do what you are hoping.  There are a few scenarios where this really helps and makes sense - but it doesn't actually have anything to do with inheritance.

It is actually quite straightforward:

```
using static MyNamespace.MyStaticClassIWantToPretendIsABaseClass;

namespace MyNamespace
{
     static class IncludesBase
     {
          // Access static class that you are pretending is a base class
     }
}
```

By playing around with this, you can make your code better or worse.  This can be really useful, but thinking about it as a base class is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Like stated earlier the C# spec say this can't be done. You can't implement a interface with static classes either. Your best bet is to change from using a static class to using a class that uses the singleton pattern. You will have only one instance (similar to how the static class works) and you will be able to inherit behavior or implement interfaces.

You read up on Singletons [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998558.aspx), [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), and [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html).

Answer (score 1):

As Christopher have pointed out, suppose we can derive static class from non-static class.

for example:

```
public class foo
{
    public int myVar;
}

public static class bar : foo { }
```

here, **bar** class derived from **foo**, hence static class **Bar** has non-static member **myVar** now, and According to the c# Specification , Static Class can not contains non-static members!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't all classes (static included) already derive from object? As in, by default?

Also, like it says, "Static class cannot derive from type.", so I don't think what you are doing is possible. Why would you want a static class to derive from a type anyways?

Answer (score 0):

It can't. You have to create a normal class to derive from some other class.

Answer (score 0):

All classes derive implicitly from `Object`. That said, although static classes (which by definition are just containers for static members) "derive" from object, there is nothing you can get from that fact.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading.

bar can't inherit from foo because foo can be instantiated and bar can't.

Comment: That's not a reason in itself. The C# spec could easily have allowed this case - it just happens not to.

Comment: Holy crap it's Jon Skeet!! *feels blessed or something* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to stop people creating instances of the class, just add a private default constructor.

Comment: My aim is to stop making instances of bar but the problem with private constructor would be that I would need to change variables and function in foo also to static to be able to access them.

Comment: In that case you should be using composition instead of inheritance; bar contains a static readonly instance of foo.

Answer (score 0):

static class can not be base class for other classes and it can not be extended.

static class can be inherited only from "object" class(.net base class).

Additional information: All classes in .net inherited from "object" class, even any static class also.

The difference is even though static class inherit "object class" it inherit only two static methods from "object" class.

Other non-static classes inherit other four methods.

Answer (score 0):

As said in other answer, the compiler message is confusing but correct. You can write:

```
static class A : object
{
}
```

of course it is not really useful to explicitly state this inheritance but the inheritance itself is actually useful in the framework as you override the object's virtual members:

```
    static class A : object
    {
        public static new string ToString()
        {
            return "I am object A";
        }

        public static new int GetHashCode()
        {
            return ToString().GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked "How can I drive it from object?". The `object` here is not an instance of another class so the answer is you don't.  The `object` refers to the System.Object base class which is the default base class for all types in .NET. The error message is bit misleading.

Just for completeness, on the flip side, a static class also cannot be inherited or extended because it is both an abstract and a sealed class.