# C# sealed class creating its instance

Tags: c#, sealed

I know this is meaning less question, but I'm confused why sealed class create its instance.

```
public sealed class SealedClass1
{
    static SealedClass1()
    {
    }

    public string GetmeassageFromSealed(string mesage)
    {
        return mesage;
    }
}
```

---

Here i decorate my constructor as private

```
public sealed class SealedClass1
        {
            static SealedClass1()
            {

           }
      private Singleton()
            {

            }
            public string GetmeassageFromSealed(string mesage)
            {
                return mesage;
            }
        }
```

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/16244430/1793811

Comment: Sealed means you cannot inherit from it. That's the difference here. You can still create an instance, but cannot inherit

Comment: Technically what you have there is a static constructor. Nowhere does it really create an instance of itself

Comment: @DavidPilkington im also surprice when its create instance   chk This https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Preview?url=/Widget/i4PmYr

Comment: @MdGhousemohi You don't print the result from the `GetmeassageFromSealed` which is why it isn't showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`sealed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed) keyword in C# means that no class can inherit from that class.

So if you have this scenario:

```
public class Test { }
```

The following is valid

```
public class NewTest: Test { }
```

However, as soon as you add the `sealed` keyword, the compiler with throw an error when trying to compile that library.

```
public sealed class Test { }

public class NewTest: Test { }
```

This would throw

> 'NewTest' cannot inherit from sealed class 'Test'.

In short, the `sealed` keyword is a compile time check to ensure that there is no inheritence.

Comment: Thank a lot this is also workin at the same time  when i create private constructor then also its working

Answer (score 1):

A Sealed Class can be **instantiated**, also it can inherit from other classes but it can not be inherited by other classes.

Comment: https:  could u please reffer this //dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: What do I have to refer?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Preview?url=/Widget/i4PmYr     go throgh it

Comment: In the code you can create the object (instance) of class Employee but you can not invoke its method GetmeassageFromSealed(string mesage) as it can not be accessed(other word inherited).

Comment: bhai i need 2 stop getting its instace

Comment: Bhai that's what I am telling you that you can create an instance of sealed class it's in its definition. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161669/discussion-between-habib-ur-rehman-and-md-ghousemohi).