# C# inheritence and static classes

Tags: c#

Why can't a static class be inherited into a normal class?

Comment: Question makes no sense.  There would be no benefit from doing so.

Comment: +1 I think it's a good question - one I hadn't thought about. If there is no perceived benefit of doing something, should a language STOP me from doing it? I don't think so.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774181/why-cant-i-inherit-static-classes

Answer (score 4):

If B inherits from (is a subclass of) A, that means an instance of B can be stored in a variable of type A, and its virtual methods will call those of class B.

For static classes, you don't have the concept of an instance of the class, so there's no way to inherit. You might have better luck with a static (singleton) reference to a regular class.

Answer (score 2):

From [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

> Creating a static class is therefore
>   basically the same as creating a class
>   that contains only static members and
>   a private constructor. A private
>   constructor prevents the class from
>   being instantiated. The advantage of
>   using a static class is that the
>   compiler can check to make sure that
>   no instance members are accidentally
>   added. The compiler will guarantee
>   that instances of this class cannot be
>   created.
>
> **Static classes are sealed and
>   therefore cannot be inherited.** They
>   cannot inherit from any class except
>   Object. Static classes cannot contain
>   an instance constructor; however, they
>   can contain a static constructor.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to inheriting from a static class, you can assign extension methods to interfaces.

Comment: helper objects as.. public static <class> function(this <class> ss)

Answer (score 1):

You can not inherit a static class - The reason is simple. **Static classes are marked as abstract and sealed in compiled IL which can be neither instantiated nor inherited**.

Answer (score -1):

> This is actually by design. There seems to be no good reason to inherit a static class. It has public static members that you can always access via the class name itself. The only reasons I have seen for inheriting static stuff have been bad ones, such as saving a couple of characters of typing.
>
> There may be reason to consider mechanisms to bring static members directly into scope (and we will in fact consider this after the Orcas product cycle), but static class inheritance is not the way to go: It is the wrong mechanism to use, and works only for static members that happen to reside in a static class.
>
> (Mads Torgersen, C# Language PM)

Source:
[Why can't I inherit static classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774181/why-cant-i-inherit-static-classes)

Comment: Please mention that there's an exact SO duplicate to the question instead of copying the winning answer from the duplicate.