# Static classes must derive from object (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am having a problem in C#, the output states:

```
Error   1   Static class 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Hello2' 
cannot derive from type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'. Static classes 
must derive from object.
```

How could I correct this?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Hello2.calculate();
        }
    }



    public class Hello : Form
    {
        public string test { get; set; }

    }


    public static class Hello2 : Form
    {
        public static void calculate()
        {
            Process.Start("test.exe");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to create a static class that derives from Form?

Comment: look at this similar question: [Why can't I inherit static classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/774181/791745)

Comment: @Tim You say that as if it's unheard of. I've come across several examples right here on SO of folks trying to achieve this functionality (which, by design, is possible in Java,) by relying on singletons when using C#.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy - I never said it was unheard of or even meant to imply it.  I was simply asking OP why they were trying to do that.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It means that `static` classes can't have `: BaseClass` in the declaration. They can't inherit from anything. (The inheritance from `System.Object` is implicit by declaring nothing.)

A `static` class can only have `static` members. Only instance members are inherited, so inheritance is useless for `static` classes. All you have to do is remove `: Form`.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to instantiate an instance of **Base-Class** as a property/field of **Derived-Class**, Then expose whatever functionality (that you like) out of it.

Comment: I fell into this one: basically I was declaring inner classes `static` as a habit from Java programming, where there is a distinction between static and non-static inner classes that does not exist in C#. Solution: just drop the "static" keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason to derive Hello and Hello2 from Form?  If not, just do:

```
public static class Hello2
{
    ...
}
```

likewise for class Hello