# How to using class with static method in C#?

Tags: c#

I want using class `ToDataTable()` to convert List to DataTable.
Problem is: class `ToDataTable()` using `static` method and it make error.
I know this error but I don't know how to resolve it.

The error code is: `Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class`

My code using is:

```
var proxyInfos = proxyL
            .Where(l => l.Contains(" US "))
            .Select(l => l.Split(' '))
            .Select(tokens => new
            {
                IP = tokens[0],
                Port = tokens[1]
            })
            .ToList();
        dtProxy = ToDataTable(proxyInfos);
```

And class to convert List to DataTable:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;
}
```

I was research on the internet. Like, change my class to static. 
But I change to static and error continues to appear:
`Static class 'MyClass.MainForm' cannot derive from type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'. Static classes must derive from object.`.

My code like this:

```
public static class MainForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static classes must derive from object (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496707/static-classes-must-derive-from-object-c)

Comment: I think you should move this method, ToDataTable into static class and make it as Extension method. So you can simply use it as, dtProxy = proxyInfos.ToDataTable();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `this`

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
```

and use as simple static method

Or move this function to separated *static* class

like

```
public static class UnilityExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: Spot-on, with a minor minor thing: CLR naming conventions hold that classes holding extension methods should be named with the suffix "Extensions", in this case "ListExtensions".

Comment: I tried add to static class but not work. But when I remove `this`, that run perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot define a form as a `static` class because it have to be instanced. TO have an extension method you need a static class, but not necessarily you need to chnage your form class. Create a new static class and put your extensions methods there. See the [MSDN docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb383977.aspx).

> Extension methods are defined as static methods but are called by
>   using instance method syntax.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> str)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);

        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return table;
    }
}
```

Another suggestion, change you `IList<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` because you can keep an extension method for more collections because the `IEnumerable` is more abstract than `IList`.

Comment: Thanks your tips - IEnumerable<T>

Answer (score 2):

You cant do `public static class MainForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form` because you cant derive static class from another class.

Although you can do this:

```
using SomeNamespace
{
    public static class FormExtension
    {
        public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
        {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure the place where you need to access the extension includes the namespace containing the Extension method.  So any `IList<T>` will have access to this `ToDataTable<T>` method.

Answer (score 0):

Move your method into static class, and make it extension method as per below given,

```
 public static class Extension
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

and replace your line,

```
dtProxy = ToDataTable(proxyInfos);
```

with,

```
dtProxy = proxyInfos.ToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I was try your code. It's work.