# Static and Sealed class differences

Tags: c#, .net, oop, static, sealed

1. Is there any class that be implemented in static class? means:

   ```
   static class ABC : Anyclass
   ```
2. Is there any class which can be inherited in both sealed class and static class?
   means:

   ```
   static class ABC : AClass {}
   ```

   And

   ```
   sealed class ABC : AClass {}
   ```

May I be wrong in some extent?

Comment: `static` has really nothing to do with `sealed`

Comment: But @ken2k, static classes are sealed by default in C#. Aren't they? static classes don't participate in inheritance at all.

Comment: Related post - [Why can't I inherit static classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/774181/465053)

Answer (score 694):

This may help you:

```
+--------------+---+-------------------------+------------------+---------------------+
|  Class Type  |   | Can inherit from others | Can be inherited | Can be instantiated | 
|--------------|---|-------------------------+------------------+---------------------+
| normal       | : |          YES            |        YES       |         YES         |
| abstract     | : |          YES            |        YES       |         NO          |
| sealed       | : |          YES            |        NO        |         YES         |
| static       | : |          NO             |        NO        |         NO          |
+--------------+---+-------------------------+------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the prompt response @HosseinNarimaniRad. I had upvoted you in the morning itself as the information was anyways correct but it was just a formatting issue. Btw, your answer deserves to be the accepted answer from the moment it was posted but it seems we will have to wait more for that :)

Comment: Sort've interesting to think of other types, based of this. Like some `root class` that can be inherited and instantiated, but can't inherit. Not sure why that'd be useful, but still

Comment: `static class Foo : object { }` is valid, but is essentially `static class Foo { }`.

Answer (score 40):

In simple words

**Static Class**

> A class can be declared static, indicating that it contains only
>   static members. It is not possible to create instances of a static
>   class using the new keyword. Static classes are loaded automatically
>   by the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR) when the program
>   or namespace containing the class is loaded.

**Sealed Class**

> A sealed class cannot be used as a base class. Sealed classes are
>   primarily used to prevent derivation. Because they can never be used
>   as a base class, some run-time optimizations can make calling sealed
>   class members slightly faster.

Answer (score 20):

You can let a `sealed` class inherit from another class, but you cannot inherit *from* a `sealed` class:

```
sealed class MySealedClass : BaseClass // is ok
class MyOtherClass : MySealedClass     // won't compile
```

A `static` class cannot inherit from other classes.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply differentiate both of them as:

```
       Sealed Class       |        Static Class
--------------------------|-------------------------
it can inherit From other | it cannot inherit From other
classes but cannot be     | classes as well as cannot be
inherited                 | inherited
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer is a **sealed class cannot be used as  a base class**.

I'm trying to show you sealed class is a derived class in the below code

```
 public sealed class SealedClass : ClassBase
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        base.Print();
    }
}
```

and another sealed feature  is only accessible with instance from it.(you can not inherit from it)

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SealedClass objSeald = new SealedClass();
        objSeald.Name = "Blah blah balh";
        objSeald.Print();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class BaseClassDemo
{ 

}

//Note
//A static class can be used as a convenient container for sets of 
//methods that just operate on input parameters and do not have to 
//get or set any internal instance fields.
//The advantage of using a static class is that the compiler can 
//check to make sure that no instance members are accidentally 
//added. The compiler will guarantee that instances of this class 
//cannot be created.


//Static class 'static type' cannot derive from type 'type'. Static 
//classes must derive from object.
 public static class StaticClassDemo : BaseClassDemo //Error



public static class StaticClassDemo
{
    //Static class must have static members
    public static void Ram()
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


//Sealed class can inherit from the base class.
public sealed class SealedClassDemo : BaseClassDemo
{

}

//We can't derive from sealed class. 
public class derivedClass:SealedClassDemo //Error



public partial class RandomClass2
{
    //we can't create instance of static class.
    StaticClassDemo demo = new StaticClassDemo() //Error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - No, you can't implement a static class.

2 - No, you can't inherited from a static or sealed class

Comment: May be you can add a little explanation on that.