# How to use bundles without HttpContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the bundles build's string in other environment, eg:HttpApplication start, Console application, etc.

But when I call

```
Scripts.Render("~/js").ToHtmlString()
```

Will be throw a Exception:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: httpContext
```

How to mock it to get result?

Comment: Can you include the call stack?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** No, it is not possible to use `Scripts.Render` without httpContext. But there might be a workaround, if you're willing to mock it (see below).

**Detailed answer:**
Microsoft made some unfortunate design decisions.
I have decompiled the Render method of the **System.Web.Optimization** (V1.1.0.0) library (part of the Microsoft.ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework, available via NUGET) and found: `Scrips.Render` (which calls `Scripts.RenderFormat` internally) calls `Scripts.Manager.RenderExplicit(tagFormat, paths)` to return the rendering result.

That function uses `this.DeterminePathsToRender(paths)` internally to resolve the paths by using `this.ResolveVirtualPath(current)`. And if you take a look at it you'll see, that it uses `this._httpContext` to resolve the path:

```
internal string ResolveVirtualPath(string virtualPath)
{
    Uri uri;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(virtualPath, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
    {
        return virtualPath;
    }
    string arg = "";
    if (this._httpContext.Request != null)
    {
        arg = this._httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
    }
    return this.ResolveUrlMethod(arg, virtualPath);
}
```

So unfortunately there is no way around httpContext.
Another way I thought of was to inherit a class myScriptClass from class Scripts and then set the internal property Context via the myScriptClass constructor. But that is also not possible because Scripts is a static class which you can't inherit from (see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774181/why-cant-i-inherit-static-classes) for details).

---

**But** you can use `BundleContext.HttpContext` to get or set the currently used HttpContext.

However, if you have only access to a particular **`BundleCollection`** object, then you have no option since its **`.Context`** property is internal.

For a console application this means that you might have to create a fake request object and HttpContext, which you have to assign to BundleContext.HttpContext before you're using the render method. You can look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452418/1016343)** or **[there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4379450/1016343)** to get more details how to do that.