# Are we able to create an overload for system methods?

Tags: c#, overloading, sealed

I am using my own `LargeWholeNumber` class for integer values. In `System.Math` class there are a number of `Max` methods for applicable types. Am I able to create an overload for this `Max` method which compares `LargeWholeNumber` instances also?

I tried creating my own `Math` class which inherits from `System.Math`, but it says `"Cannot inherit from sealed class 'Math'"`.

Thanks in advance for your advices.

Comment: [Why can't I inherit static classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774181/why-cant-i-inherit-static-classes)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774181/why-cant-i-inherit-static-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, basically. For *instance* methods, you can use extension methods to add new pseudo-overloads. This is not possible for static methods.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot override a non-virtual or static method. The overridden base method must be virtual, abstract, or override.

reference from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx

So if the System method is virtual, you can override it. If no, you can't.

If you want to override a System method is non-virtual, I recommend you use extension method

Comment: The question was not `override`. It was *overload*. That is very different, and does not relate to `virtual` / `abstract` / `override`. I think you've given a fair answer to a completely different question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inherit a sealed class. The best solution for your problem would be to write your own Math class or use extension methods.

```
    void Main()
    {
        var a = new LargeWholeNumber{Number = 2};
        var b = new LargeWholeNumber{Number = 3};

        var bigger = a.Max(b);
        var bigger2 = ExtMethods.Max(a,b);
    }


    public class LargeWholeNumber 
    {
        public int Number {get;set;}
    }


    public static class ExtMethods
    {
        public static LargeWholeNumber Max(this LargeWholeNumber inNumber, 
LargeWholeNumber secondNumber)
        {
            if(inNumber.Number >= secondNumber.Number)
                return inNumber;
            else 
                return secondNumber;
        }

    }
```