# Does .Net itself have classes which cannot be inherited from?

Tags: c#, inheritance, sealed

I am curious to know if there are any samples in c#. I can't think of a single sample forbidding inheritance rather than some commercial intentions, so I would like to know some real world examples in c# itself.

I know about sealed classes, I'm just looking for some examples in c# itself, something rather than value types and structs which are implicitly sealed.

Comment: I'm not sure about "commercial intentions", but `sealed` classes prevent [Fragile Base Class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) issues. One day to day example is the [`Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) class - you really don't want to inherit it and change its behaviour.

Comment: Aha, :) that makes sense now, your thread example really makes sense. And thanks for the link:)

Comment: No problem :) If you want a complete list, you can browse or download .NET reference sources and search for all other cases http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot inherit from any struct, [`sealed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) class, or [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) class. C# also prohibits using a number of 'special' types including [`Delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as it provides other constructs for using these.

The most obvious example that comes to my mind is [`System.String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you were to try to inherit from it like this:

```
public class CustomString : String { }
```

You'll see this error:

> 'CustomString': cannot derive from sealed type 'string'

And there are **many** other examples in the .Net framework. I did a quick comparison using reflection and in `mscorlib` (v4.0) alone there are 856 sealed public types, compared to 619 non-sealed public types (which includes interfaces).

Comment: Rather than value types, such as int and structa, do you have any other example in mind?

Comment: `ListItem` is [another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem)

Comment: @Hossein I named `string` as one example, but there are countless others.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it has. All the classes that are `sealed`, they cannot be used as base classes.

For more information about `sealed` classes, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx).

Some examples of `sealed` classes in .NET are the following:

- [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [System.Net.HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: !i know about sealed classes, im just loking for some examples in c# itself, something rather than value types and strucs wich are implicitly sealedCan you name some?

Comment: Sure thing, `System.String`, as already p.s.w.g has already pointed out is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `sealed` class, `static` class cannot also be inherited, see [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774181/why-cant-i-inherit-static-classes). E.g :   `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

```
public static class Inherited : System.Linq.Enumerable
{
}
```

This is not working too.