# Default for generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0

Is it possible to do something like

```
public class PriorityQueue<TValue, TPriority=int> where TPriority : IComparable
```

(note the `=int`) ?

Before you suggest it, yes, I know I can just add another line:

```
public class PriorityQueue<TValue> : PriorityQueue<TValue, int> { }
```

But I'm wondering if it's possible to do it as a param.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

No.  There is no option for default types on generic types in C#.

Your second example is often the "best" option available, if you need this behavior.